# how to use the following timer service in angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6, angular10

How to use it in component to show a timer/ count down  number? Is it a good practice to have a service like this?

```
import { Subscription, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class IntervalRunnerOptions {
    constructor(
        public callback:()=>void,
        public period:number=1000,
        public initialDelay:number=0,
        public TotalTime: number) {
    }
}

export class IntervalRunner {
    subscription: Subscription = null;

    start(options:IntervalRunnerOptions) {
        if(this.subscription==null) {
            this.subscription = timer(options.initialDelay, options.period).subscribe(result => options.callback());
        }
    }
    
    stop() {
        if(this.subscription!=null) {
            this.subscription.unsubscribe();
            this.subscription = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6dl73p?file=src/app/app.component.html) to show you how to use it

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <button (click)="start()">Start</button>
    <button (click)="stop()">Stop</button>
    <p>
      <em>{{ message }}</em>
    </p>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  message: string;
  constructor(private runner: IntervalRunner) {}

  start() {
    this.runner.start(
      new IntervalRunnerOptions(e => (this.message = "Hi: " + e), 1000, 0, 5)
    );
  }

  stop() {
    this.runner.stop();
  }
}
```

I've modified the callback to accept an argument `public callback: (e: any) => void` then passe the result of the timer to it.

Comment: how can i show a countdown numbers 5,4,3,21,1 using this service in component?

Comment: I've updated my answer and the stackblitz to show you the numbers in the template ... But there's no countdown, that's not what your service doing